# Check if a user has responded to a direct message

Tags: api, twitter

I am wondering if it is possible to determine if the current logged in user has responded to a direct message from another user with the Twitter API.

I have been looking over the Twitter API [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/direct_messages) and I can't seem to find a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no specific API call for this, and DMs don't have an "in reply to" field.

The best you can do is look at https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/direct_messages/sent and check what time a message was sent.  That will tell you if a DM was sent *after* receiving one - but not if it's a reply.